# Invalid filter clause using $filter

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm currently developing an app based on Microsoft Graph's Node.js [template](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample) for listening to notifications. I'm running into an issue while trying to use $filter. My goal is to only receive notifications if the email if from `someone@foo.edu`.

Here's a snippet of my POST request so far:

```
postData(
    encodeURI('/beta/subscriptions?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq \'someone@foo.edu\''),
    token.accessToken,
    JSON.stringify(subscriptionConfiguration),
    (requestError, subscriptionData) => {...})
);
```

The path, at least what I think is supposed to be `graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq 'someone@foo.edu'`, however I get this error as the response:

```
{ error:
   { code: 'BadRequest',
     message: 'Invalid filter clause',
     innerError:
      { 'request-id': 'f010410d-eac2-4322-a2ef-d76a038408ed',
        date: '2019-05-06T04:20:11' } } }
```

The post request code is not the issue, it works perfectly without the $filter query. Still, you can find it [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample/blob/master/helpers/requestHelper.js#L12-L38).

Some help would be greatly appreciated.